# Add dummy layer so that layer with "soft light" blending mode is visible by itself

Tags: qgis, raster, layers

I have a QGIS project with three raster layers:

1. SRTM GeoTiff (blending mode: SOFT LIGHT; color ramp: Viridis)
2. Google Terrain (blending mode normal)
3. Google Satellite (blending mode normal)

The problem is: if I display ONLY layer 1, nothing is visible, because it has nothing below to "blend with".

So my question is: is there a way to create a "solid color" layer, so that an upper layer with blending mode different than "normal" (and particularly with "soft light") can be visible somehow?

---

If I hide layer 2, I have the following result:

[image]

And if I display only layers 1 and 2 (layer 3 might be one or off), this is the result:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps the Create constant raster layer tool will help. Tool description: "Given an input raster layer and a value, this algorithm generates a new layer with the same extent and cell size as the input one, and all cells with the specified value."

Comment: @csk Sounds interesting. How would I do that? Is there a menu?

Comment: You can find this tool in the processing toolbox (Processing menu > Toolbox > Raster tools)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually just make a polygon layer containing a single feature covering the whole mapped area to achieve this, and style it with a simple fill of the desired colour.